# The Login block has vanished

Tags: 7, debugging

I haven't changed it in */admin/structure/blocks* and it is still there.

All that I can think that I installed a few modules to try them out and then disabled them and maybe that caused it.

In any case, my users can't log in and I am in big trouble.

How to go about debugging the problem?  Thanks.

---

Update: I am not logged in (I see "Log in or register to post comments"). Even when I load /user/logout the login block is not there (not in the HTML)

The "recent log messages" shows nothing out of the way.

Comment: First check that other blocks are displaying in that region. Maybe you have edited the template file and removed the block region

Comment: Also, check that you're not logged in.  If you are, the block won't show!

Comment: check you ```dblog``` for errors. debug the html to see if anything is hiding it.

Comment: @tecjam +1  I didn't edit the template. The block is the first in its sidebar and the others display

Comment: @Chapabu +1 I tried several browsers also private browsing mode & a different PC. Still the same problem

Comment: @karthik +1 No sign of it in the HTML, so apparently not generated. I am off now to check the dblog. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modules you were experimenting with and then disabled, did you go through the uninstall process?
Also, flush you caches.

I hope that helps.

Comment: +1 and the answer. Whatever was wrong, that fixed it (probably flushing the cache, I would guess).  Thanks for saving my life